# Why does my polygon shrink when I zoom using D3

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to zoom out and still allow a tooltip in my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RyLWhRDOQTqFKhgA1vvy), however, the tooltip is getting warped (i.e. too small too large) when I zoom in or out.

I have double checked and the numbers and the polygon with...

```
<polygon points="0,0 0,197.9261932373047 131.95079040527344,197.9261932373047 131.95079040527344,0 50,0 37.5,-15 25,0" height="212.9261932373047" width="131.95079040527344" fill="#D8D8D8" opacity="0.75" transform="translate(212.5,238.74583334568888)"></polygon>
```

seems to match the BoundingRect height and width. Is there some sort of distortion happening here since I am zoomed out?

```
var br = div[0][0].parentNode.getBoundingClientRect(),
  foHeight = br.height,
  foWidth = br.width;
```

If you need the tooltip to stick around just comment out the remove line

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to zoom the tooltip polygon but rather leave it a static size?  If you zoom the `g` containing the ploygon, it's going to scale like everything else.  You could move it into the parent SVG that's not zoomed:  https://plnkr.co/edit/kyJbslMpXJsahL9FbZuI?p=preview

Comment: No what I am saying is in this example the polygon is based on the tooltip HTML size. However when you zoom out the polygon seems to shrink (or grow) faster than the HTML